How to config a reverse proxy for domain IP address in Google Cloud Platform
I am using a domain from Cloud Domains to redirect to a Minecraft server hosted on a TCP server. However, Cloud DNS exposes my server's real IP address when someone performs a lookup. I want to hide my server's IP using a proxy or by forwarding connections through another IP address.
I’ve tried creating a VM to act as a relay, but the cost is too high, and it feels like overkill. I also explored using load balancers, but most tutorials focus on VM configurations, which I want to avoid. I attempted to configure a load balancer-like setup, but the health check failed—possibly because the server runs on a TCP port.
What is the best way to hide my server’s real IP while keeping the setup simple and cost-effective?

All TCP connections involve a Listening Port (Server) and a client that connects to it.
Server IP Leaking
Some (server) applications "Leak" their IP address meaning that the server knows it's IP address and may send that address to the client as part of a higher level protocol, the usual solution for that is just to run the server on a private subnet (192.168.x.y) so that the server cannot leak its public address. Additionally you might need to firewall the server so it cannot initiate any outbound connections to the internet.
I don't know if the Minecraft protocol has this problem or not.
Client
In order to connect to a server a client must connect to an IP address. That IP may be the "real" IP of the server - if the machine is directly connected to the internet.
Otherwise it is the IP address of "something" that is "forwarding" the traffic: a home router, a proxy, NAT/Firewall, VPN, TOR router, etc.
Ultimately the question is why do you want to hide your IP:

Offensive - meaning you are doing nefarious things.
Defensive - meaning you want protection from nefarious things.

If offensive, it is probably off-topic here.
If defensive, its unlikely that hiding your IP would provide any protection against any attack that would typically be leveraged against a Minecraft server.
